# Using Other Column as Identifier in Polymorphic Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using Eloquent on my project and I am currently facing a problem with regards to polymorphic relations. What I would like to do is to specify another column instead of the primary key in morphing relationship such that:

Products

- `id`
- `product_number`
- `description`

User

- `id`
- `username`

Photos

- `id`
- `path`
- `imageable_id`
- `imageable_type`

In this scenario, I would like to create a relation with both the products and the users table, but in the product relationship, instead of putting the ID as the relationship identifier, I would like to put the `product_number` because of some reasons. Is it possible as of version 5.1?

Thanks,

Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible by specifying the local key like so:

```
return $this->morphMany('App\Photos', 'imageable', null, null, 'product_number' );
```